# Creating Python submodule

Tags: python, module

I want to create a tool called `unifile` for saving and opening files
like this `unifile.open.yaml("file.yaml")`.

This is my structure:

```
unifile
|
├-open
|    └--__init__.py
|
└-save
     └--__init__.py
```

Code that call my module:

```py
import unifile
a = unifile.open.yaml("file.yaml")
```

**open/**init**.py**

```
import yaml
class open():
    def yml(self, file_path):
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as yaml_conf:
                yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(yaml_conf)

            return yaml_file
        except OSError:
            print("Can't load yaml")
```

1 error if I import `unifile` always say:

> module unifile has no atribute open

2 error in `__init__.py` I can't open file

> [pylint] Context manager 'open' doesn't implement **enter** and **exit**. [not-context-manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here adding solution to ur problem, make  your project structure like this.

add `unifile/__init__.py` file in the unifile itself not in other modules.

[image]

then `unifile/open/_open.py` file content

```
import yaml

class Open():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def yml(self, file_path):
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as yaml_conf:
                yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(yaml_conf)

            return yaml_file
        except OSError:
            print("Can't load yaml")
```

content of the `unifile/__init__.py`  file

```
from .open._open import Open
```

in terminal run the program like this

[image]

Also, It is better to create a object element first then proceed ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues, two answers.

First, you should add an init file in unifile. With this, Python will understand that unifile is a package with a sub package.

Second, *open* is a built-in function and you overwrite it by calling your class *open*. Change your class name and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are getting this error because unifile is not a package. There isn't any ***init**.py* file at the top level same as open and save. You also cannot call *open.yml* directly, because *open* is a class in package *open*, so either you will have to import *open* from *open*, create its instance and then call iml on that instance.

   ```
    from open import open

    a = open().yml('file.yml')
   ```
2. You are getting this error, because you are trying to override an existing keyword in Python **open** which you should strictly prohibit doing. So you should name your class anything except a reserved keyword.